How to create a new list of dicts based on 2 lists with added value of both lists of dicts that have the same key
I have two list of dict:
list1 = [{"month": "Jan", "amount":1}, {"month": "Feb", "amount":4}]
list2 = [{"month": "Jan", "amount":2}, {"month": "Feb", "amount":4}]

how can I create a new list of dict with the same keys and add the values of the "amount" of each dict that has the same "month"?
target = [{"month": "Jan", "amount":3}, {"month": "Feb", "amount": 8}]


Do you have a lot of these to do?  If it were ME, I would create a new intermediate dictionary where the key is the month name and the value is the amount.  Now, it's easy to add in each new entry and convert it back later.

Thanks for the answer Tim! Could you elaborate on that abit? what do you mean intermediate dictionary? mind giving me a sample?

This is basic data manipulation. Use for loops, if statements... read tutorials... [ask]

This implements what I auggested above:
from collections import defaultdict

list1 = [{"month": "Jan", "amount":1}, {"month": "Feb", "amount":4}]
list2 = [{"month": "Jan", "amount":2}, {"month": "Feb", "amount":4}]
months = defaultdict(int)
for l in (list1,list2):
    for d in l:
        months[d['month']] += d['amount']

print(months)
target = [{'month':k,'amount':v} for k,v in months.items()]
print(target)

Output:
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Jan': 3, 'Feb': 8})
[{'month': 'Jan', 'amount': 3}, {'month': 'Feb', 'amount': 8}]

I used a defaultdict for simplicity, but a normal dictionary would also work with the usual if d['month'] not in months: protection.

Thanks Tim! This is exactly what I needed thanks!

How about this:
list1 = [{"month": "Jan", "amount":1}, {"month": "Feb", "amount":4}]
list2 = [{"month": "Jan", "amount":2}, {"month": "Feb", "amount":4}]

count = dict()

for lst in list1 + list2:
    m = lst.get('month')
    if m not in count:
        count[m] = 0
    count[m] += int(lst.get('amount', 0))

target = [{'month': m, 'amount': c} for m, c in count.items()]

